# How to set up config so that Thymeleaf will render my html template

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

This is my first question on Stack, so I apologize if it's not formatted correctly.

I have an application that sends out an email using an HTML template when a shipment has changed status. The sending mechanism is working as it should, and it is finding my template just fine. The problem is that the email that is sent is just my HTML in plain text and not rendered at all. So instead of a nicely rendered HTML page, the body of the email is just code.

I think the problem lies somewhere in the config file. I have another app that is using an older version of Thymeleaf and works exactly as it should, but unfortunately the setup for that is outdated and no longer works. Also, I have attempted a few different config options, as shown in the commented out portion of my code.

I have checked every line of the HTML template to make sure there are no unclosed tags or symbols that would escape the HTML. All data is being pulled over from the controller into the template, and I have checked to make sure the template is displayed properly in a browser. It's just when it puts everything together and sends the email that it fails to work and doesn't render.

I have included my pom file, a relevant portion from the app.config, and the app.config itself. Again, this is my first question on here, so if I'm missing something I'd be happy to add it, and if the question is formatted wrong I apologize and am open to critique on how to do it correctly.

Thank you.

The app is using Spring Boot 2.1.1, Spring 5, and Thymeleaf 3.0.11. I have also tried using Spring 4, as well as downgraded versions of Thymeleaf.

**pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.api</groupId>
<artifactId>tms-scheduled-tasks</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>tms-scheduled-tasks</name>
<description>TMS Scheduled Tasks</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
        <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

**From application.properties**

```
# Thymeleaf
 spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
 spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

**AppConfig**

```
package com.api.tmsscheduledtasks.config;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import 
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine;
import 
org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.api")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/WEB-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

/**
 * According to some resource I can no longer remember
 */
    @Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(this.applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());

    return viewResolver;
}

/**
 * According to Baeldung
 */
//    @Bean
//    public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
//        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
//        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine((templateResolver())));
//        resolver.setContentType("text/html");
//        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
//        resolver.setViewNames(ArrayUtil.array("*.html"));
//
//        return resolver;
//    }
// 
//    private ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(ITemplateResolver 
templateResolver) {
//        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
//        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
//        return engine;
//    }
//
//    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
//        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new 
SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
//        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
//        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
//        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
//        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
//        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
//
//        return templateResolver;
//    }
    /**
     * According to thymeleaf.org
     */
//    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext 
applicationContext) {
//        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
//    }
//
//    @Bean
//    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
//        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
//        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
//        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
//        return resolver;
//    }
//
//    @Bean
//    public TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
//        SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
//        engine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
//        engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
//        return engine;
//    }
//
//    private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
//        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new 
SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
//        resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
//        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
//        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
//        return resolver;
//    }
    /**
    * Old setup from other app
    */
//    @Bean
//    public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
//        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new 
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
//        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
//        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
//
//        return templateResolver;
//    }
```

## EDIT

After talking to a colleague at work he discovered the issue. It turns out I overlooked the Email class where everything was being built. It was a fairly silly mistake on my part, but I'll post the original code below and then the answer.

```
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;

public class Email {
private SimpleMailMessage message;

public Email setFrom(String from) {
    getMessage().setFrom(from);

    return this;
}

public Email setTo(String to) {
    getMessage().setTo(to);

    return this;
}

public Email setSubject(String subject) {
    getMessage().setSubject(subject);

    return this;
}

public Email setText(String text) {
    getMessage().setText(text);

    return this;
}

public SimpleMailMessage build() {
    return getMessage();
}

protected SimpleMailMessage getMessage() {
    if (message == null) {
        message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    }

    return this.message;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again. The solution was very simple, but I it was something I had overlooked in the `Email` class, I should have removed the `SimpleMailMessage` and replaced it with a `MimeMessagePreparator.` Nothing was wrong at all in the config or any of that. Just me overlooking an old method from when it was set up and forgetting to change it. Here is the change that was made.

```
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;

public class Email {
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String subject;
    private String text;

    public Email setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;

        return this;
    }

    public Email setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;

        return this;
    }

    public Email setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;

        return this;
    }

    public Email setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;

        return this;
    }

    public MimeMessagePreparator build() {
        return mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
            messageHelper.setFrom(from);
            messageHelper.setTo(to);
            messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
            messageHelper.setText(text, true);
        };
    }
}
```